# Making one specific element of my WP site cross browser compatible

Tags: wordpress-theming, cross-browser

I am building [www.chaloapps.com](http://www.chaloapps.com) using a Theme I bought from WooThemes. 
When I view it in Firefox, the quote right below the featured content area is all on one line.

When I view it in Safari, Chrome, and IE, the quote is broken up into two lines.

What can I add to the CSS so that it stays on one line in **all** browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
.woo-sc-quote p {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or maybe:

```
.woo-sc-quote p {
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

... in case it should overlap too far.

This one would work, too - but looks crappy i this case:

```
.woo-sc-quote p {
   padding: 0 0 0 38px;
}
```